# Hibernate ignores left join results

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a simple `Field` entity that have to load child `Selector` entity using join.

```java
@Entity
public class Field implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private Long userId;

    private String selectorId;

    // ......

    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "userId", referencedColumnName = "userId", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "selectorId", referencedColumnName = "selectorId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    @ManyToOne
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private Selector selector;
}
```

Hibernate does it and generates this sql. Looks good:

```sql
SELECT field0_.id AS id1_25_0_,
       -- ... i've cut redundant lines ...
       selector1_.id AS id1_54_1_,
       selector1_.selector_id AS selector4_54_1_,
       selector1_.user_id AS user_i5_54_1_,
       selector1_.url AS url6_54_1_
FROM field field0_
         LEFT OUTER JOIN selector selector1_
                         ON field0_.user_id = selector1_.user_id AND field0_.selector_id = selector1_.selector_id
WHERE field0_.id=?;
```

But after executing the query above, Hibernate immediately generates and executes second sql for each `Field` to select the `Selector` entity again.
How to prevent executing the second sql? `Selector` already should be loaded in the first query with join.

```sql
SELECT selector0_.id AS id1_54_0_,
       selector0_.selector_id AS selector4_54_0_,
       selector0_.user_id AS user_i5_54_0_,
       selector0_.url AS url6_54_0_
FROM selector selector0_
WHERE selector0_.user_id=?
  AND selector0_.selector_id=?;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seem to be fixed in Hibernate 6.0

Please see the [link](https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/fetch-join-results-in-too-many-sql-queries/6193)